# where do jar files have to be at runtime? I'm using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm creating an app that uses a jar file I downloaded, I added the jar to the project by going to 'project properties' then going to 'library' and adding the jar under 'compile' and 'run'.  when when I get to the part of the program that uses a function from this particular library, I get a noclassdeffound error.  how do I find the location to put this jar file at runtime?  this is the stack trace

```
[#|2015-01-22T15:39:50.446-0500|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=109;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[generateScripts]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet generateScripts threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap
    at tsschecks.generateScripts.processRequest(generateScripts.java:94)
    at tsschecks.generateScripts.doPost(generateScripts.java:179)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.BidiMap
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: The jar has to be on your file system somewhere, in your class path.

Comment: There is a difference between ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFound error. Please paste the entire stack trace you are getting and see if there are any other dependencies that jar/ class needs at runtime.

Comment: And have you downloaded and added the common-collections4.jar in your runtime you said?

Comment: I downloaded it, and I added it under project properties -> libraries -> under the 'compile' and 'run' tabs.  is there anywhere else I would need to add it?  I don't know if it matters but it's a web app running on a glassfish server.  would this be more of a glassfish issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add your library to your Project in the project properties.

You may need to create the library if you haven't done.

Please refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqhQY7U9Rlc&feature=youtu.be) if you need further help

Answer (score 0):

Some jar files requires other jar files called dependencies. Using Maven projects will solve this issue, but if you are just create a java project and added your own jar files, then you need to include all these dependencies one-by-one.

You can search for dependencies for the main jar file you added via google. However, error message reports some useful information where that class is missing. Copy and search for the error message or method name that throw the error.

Anyhow, if you want to know where your lib is located, first open your project explorer view from Window menu. Open your project and go to Library folder. Right click on it and choose properties. Project properties window will be opened. Select Libraries then compile tab. This is where your included classes are. Add more class here, though.

Normally your jar files are within your project jar. To find out, Hit F11 or Run menu > buid project . After success build, go to where  your project is located. go to project properties again and this time select source from left list. It will show you the path.

Go to that path, go to dist folder an there will be your project.jar, readme.txt and a lib folder where all your external jars are located.

to run your project which it is mostly what you will use as compiled byte-codes, double click on your project.jar file.